# Implement a routine that runs 3 times a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This is my for loop

```
for (j in 1:npares) {...}
```

How can I run this for loop 3 times, for example?

I want to repeat this loop 3 times. Thats all.

Is there any special command o do that?

Comment: You could just wrap it in another `for(i in 1:3)` loop

Comment: Something like this: `for(i in 1:3) {for (j in 1:npares) {...}}´?

Comment: Yes. That should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jludewig answer should definitely work but you could also do it like this:

```r
n <- 0
while(n < 3)
{
 for (j in 1:npares) {...}
 n <- n + 1        
}
```